# Telnet BBS — server side with Synchronet

Tags: commodore-64, bbs

I have restored a Commodore 64 and equipped it with a "WiFi modem", which allows me to connect to Telnet BBS sites over the internet. [So far so good](https://twitter.com/0xF2/status/1544450601538428935) for the client side.

Server-side, I am looking to host my own BBS using the [Synchronet](http://wiki.synchro.net) package on a modern host, and what I want to host is relatively simple (a news screen scraped from a web site or something like it), but I have been unable to find an example to start from. Someone hit me with the clue stick please.

Comment: so the question is basically "how do I set up synchronet on a modern host"?

Comment: I can set up synchronet... I am looking for a working example of a telnet BBS site.

Comment: Also confused as to what you are asking... Is this more than setting up Synchronet and having a domain name assigned to the host running it? Are you asking how you can populate Synchronet with posts that are "scraped from a web site"?

Comment: Synchronet is modern software, running in modern (e.g. PC/RPi) environment, active maintained ([latest Version Jan 2022](http://www.synchro.net/)). This means it's certainly off-topic on RC.SE. Moreso as the question seems to be all about handling and content collection, which are all tasks confined to Synchronet.

Comment: @BrianH the latter.

Comment: Geez thanks. It would be nice if the new mood of StackExchange was helping folks with honest questions rather than the "offtopic nazi" atmosphere prevailing these days.